# "Citizen Patrol" badge mis-titled

Tags: feature-request, badges

The explanation for the "Citizen Patrol" badge is simply "First flagged post", which is admirably concise, but wrong.  It should be "Flagged first post", because the badge goes to the flagger, not the poster. (And yes, I was genuinely confused when I first read it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the badge descriptions describe the object of the action that causes you to get the relative badge; for example:

- First rollback: The rollback has been done by you, not from somebody else on your posts.
- First down vote: The down-vote has been done by you, not from somebody who down-voted one of your posts.
- First edit: The edit has been done by you, not from somebody who edited one of your posts.
- First retag: The retag has been done by you, not from somebody who changed one of the tags used in one of your question.

The description of the badge is intentionally not clear because, as [Jeff Atwood said](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/a-bevy-of-new-badges/):

> Badges are supposed to be a little mysterious; you should view them as minor puzzles with obvious hints.
>
> - What activity is this badge referring to?
> - How do I perform this activity?
> - Why is this activity important and necessary?
> - Who should normally perform this activity, and when?

Comment: On the first half of this: yes, exactly my point.  But thanks for the second half, which explains a lot.